# How to make a movie clip or graphic open up when a button is clicked in Flash?

Tags: flash, button, adobe

I have converted my button into a button symbol and I want it so that whenever I click the button, it opens up a movie clip or graphic that is stored in my Library. 
Adobe Flash

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are in AS3. You have several options, but the easiest one would be to :

- give your button an instance name :
  click on it, open the properties panel and fill the instance name field, for    example with "myButton".
- give your movieclip a linkage name in your library : right-click on it, open the properties panel, check the Export for actionScript box and fill the Class field, with myClip.
- listen to the click event on your button :

  ```
  myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickMyButton);
  ```
- add the clip on the stage when you click it :

  ```
  function clickMyButton(evt:MouseEvent):void {addChild(myClip);}
  ```